# Suppress lint warning on view level

Tags: android, maven, suppress-warnings, lint

I am getting the following error from lint: `InconsistentLayout`. Sometimes this is expected as the tablet and phone layout differ. That's why the last couple sentences of the lint warning:

> There *are* cases where this is intentional. For example, you may
>   have a dedicated large tablet layout which adds some extra widgets
>   that are not present in the phone version of the layout. As long as
>   the code accessing the layout resource is careful to handle this
>   properly, it is valid. In that case, you can suppress this lint check
>   for the given extra or missing views, or the whole layout

Perfect, I agree. I want to suppress the warning, but only for the specific view I am getting it, not for the entire layout containing it (to avoid hiding unintentional errors). I am usaully configuring lint suppress warning in `lint.xml` file in my project that maven uses while building.

I suppress the warnigns on layout level like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="InconsistentLayout" >

        <ignore path="res/layout/my_layout.xml" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

How can I declare lint to ignore just the view id I verified is OK to be inconsistent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the following attribute to the view:

```
tools:ignore="InconsistentLayout"
```

and add the namespace prefix declaration

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to the view element or one of its parents.

Further reading: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html#src